# Choose at runtime array or vector in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, types

I have a problem described as below ::

```
    class datad {
    private:
        int *a;
        int _size;
        vector<int> v;

    public:
        datad(int arr[], int size) {
            _size = size;
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                a[i] = arr[i];
        }
        datad(vector<int> ve)
        {
            v = ve;
            _size = ve.size();
        }

        void printdata()
        {
             // print data which the object has been initialized with
             // if object is initialized with vector then print vector
             // array print array
        }
    };

   int main()
   {
        // print only vector data
    int a[] = { 9,4,8,3,1,6,5 };
    datad d(v1);
    d.printdata();

    // print only array data

    datad d1(a, 7);
    d1.printdata();
 }
```

I need to find the way the object is initialized and then based on the same should be able to printdata accrodingly. 
Can someone help me understand if it is possible at all?

Comment: You know that `vector<T>` can return a pointer that is binary compatible with `T*`, right?

Comment: You got your answer, but I still really want to know... why do both?

Comment: I do understand, im putting a point here if i can or not. This is not part of my code which i am using. This is just an example to what i am looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Add a `bool usesVector` to your class and set it to `true` or `false` in each constructor as appropriate. Then, in `printdata`, simply check the value of the boolean.

*Or* you can set `size` to `-1` in the vector case (as it's otherwise unused) and just check for that.

By the way, your array implementation is broken, because you never allocate any memory for it. You'd be *much* better off using *only* the vector version. You can still initialise that vector from array data if you wish.

Comment: +1 for "using only the vector version" No sense of keeping that dangerous int* around when you have access to the stl.

Comment: I accept your solution, but my point is to find out a way to what the object has been initialized with. This is just an example to put my point.

Comment: Logically im expecting there should be more powers to an object to understand its state or how its been initialized. Looks like it has very little practical application in C++. Anyways thank you dear.

Comment: @raghureddy: What constitutes the state of an object is determined by the person who writes the class. That's you. You can accomplish it in the manner I explained in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a flag in respective constructor and check that flag during the printing method.

I hope this is for learning purposes, otherwise as noted you maybe better of using just the vector version. When using dynamic memory management in class you need to be aware of things like rule of [three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) and I guess there is also rule of five.

Comment: Or set the size to a negative value in one case, and save the space of another member...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, it's not stealing if I share it willingly :)

Comment: @StoryTeller: It is when I don't give you any attribution :)